# Better folding on file open -- based on file length?

Tags: folding, startup

I like having files be opened folded, specially when they are large. However, when they are small, it can be an overkill (like a markdown file with a single heading). In such cases, I'd like to open top-level folds single level or perhaps unfold everything if the file shorter than some fixed line length (or better -- if it fits on my screen with current size of vim)

How could I achieve this dynamic behavior on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch `BufWinEnter` and set `foldlevel` appropriately

```
augroup adjust_fold | au!
    autocmd BufWinEnter * let &l:foldlevel = line('$') > 100 ? 0 : line('$') > winheight(0) ? 1 : 99
augroup end
```